# Android emulator screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

From your experience as an android developer what emulator screen sizes do you use?

Are there a couple that tend to catch most UI sizing issues or do you test your app in every size and density?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While coding, try to cover at least one of each from this table: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing . After most of the work is done, I would suggest try every combination you'll find in real devices you plan to deploy your app.

My very basic list while I am designing the UI is:

- WQVGA 120 dpi
- HVGA 160 dpi
- WVGA 160 dpi
- WVGA 240 dpi

Add 480x640 240 dpi if you want to support small screens.

You can use the pie chart here to have an idea of relative screen size usage: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

BTW, I have use AVDs from Donut to Gingerbread also.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, I test on every size and density that I intend the app to run on. It's irresponsible not to do so.

But beware of densities; because of dpi scaling, you may be running what you think is an hdpi emulator, but the emulator is loading mdpi resources (or vice versa). It's a good practice when testing to log the reported density during `onCreate` of your launch activity. (My approach, though, is to use an app icon for each density that displays the density, at least until I want to test the real app icons. That way I can tell from the home screen what the emulator thinks it is running.)

Answer (score 0):

you should test your app in every size , in order to be sure that your app will work fine in every android phone ;

and for density , try to create your UI with dip :)

hope it helps